# RadioButton does not switch from "true" to "false"

Tags: android, radio-button, manifest

I have a problem with my RadioButton which I declerate in my activity_main.xml:

```
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/RadioButton01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/RadioButton00"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/RadioButton00"        
    android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/RadioButton00" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/RadioButton02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/RadioButton01"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/RadioButton01"
    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/RadioButton01" />
```

Some of this RadioButtons are set programaticly to "true". But the user should have the right to make it to "false" if he clicks on it. At the moment it doesn't. If I click on it, it just still be true and does not switch to false.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {    

private RadioButton RB1, RB2;   

int[][] RBTrue = new int[3][16];    

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     



    RB1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.RadioButton00);

    RB2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.RadioButton01);

    }

    public void setRadioButtons()
    {
        steine sander = new steine();
        sander.setSteine();
        RBTrue = sander.getSteine();



        if(RBTrue[0][0] == 1)
            RB1.setChecked(true);       
        if(RBTrue[0][1] == 1)
            RB2.setChecked(true);
     }
```

So it's pretty easy. I gonna give an array and check it if it's 1 or not. If it is the RadioButton switching to true. But sometimes the user need to switch it back to false. At the moment it's not possible.

Comment: how u can declare RadioButton Manifest.xml ??Please explain

Comment: why you declare in manifest file?

Comment: why don't using CheckBox?

Comment: I'm sorry. I meant activity_main.xml

Comment: post your code what  u have done

Comment: Use radio Group or checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radio_group"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/RadioButton01"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="...."
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/RadioButton02"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:text="....."
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </RadioGroup>
```

then inside activity,,,

```
    RadioGroup rgGroup=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radio_group);  



           int selectedId = rgGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            RadioButton rBtn1 =(RadioButton)findViewById(selectedId);
            Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this,
            rBtn1.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare the `RadioButton`s inside a `RadioGroup`([details here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html)).